# Angular JSON only works with local json files but not urls

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I've just been introduced to Angularjs and I was trying to use $http.get. The page only works if the url I give is a local 'calender.json' But when I give a url, it spits out a blank page. Could someone please help me understand my error?

Comment: THIS is CORS issue, check your console..

Comment: May need to use jsonp request for CORs.

Comment: `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`  it appears that you either need to adjust the server or use jsonp.

Comment: not all API's can be reached using ajax due to `same origin policy`. This one is not CORS enabled and if they don't serve jsonp you will need to use a proxy to get data. On a side note...strongly suggest upgrading angular version to more current one. A lot of things have changed since 1.02

Comment: I found out today that if the url is a 404, chrome sometimes decides to spit out a cross origin error, since a page that can't be found also doesn't have a access-control-allow-origin header. So it can be worth to check if the url that you're trying to fetch actually exists.

Comment: @Chrillewoodz can open that url right in browser and see the headers aren't correct and is valid url

Answer (score 2):

As other have pointed out in the comments to your question, this is a CORS issue.  To easily resolve this issue you can change your `$http.get()` call to `$http.jsonp()`.  This alone will not resolve the issue, however.  You will also need to adjust the url by adding another query parameter like so (using your provided url):
`https://ssl.uh.edu/calendar/api/?view=7day&format=json&distinct=1&callback=JSON_CALLBACK`

The callback=JSON_CALLBACK tells the server that you are querying that you want it to wrap the JSON response in a function named JSON_CALLBACK, which is a special angular keyword.  Check out the docs for more info: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

tl;dr version:
change `$http.get("https://ssl.uh.edu/calendar/api/?view=7day&format=json&distinct=1")` to `$http.jsonp("https://ssl.uh.edu/calendar/api/?view=7day&format=json&distinct=1&callback=JSON_CALLBACK")`

Comment: good catch that it actually serves jsonp. Worth noting though that the string `JSON_CALLBACK` is just a placeholder for an internally created callback name

Comment: Yeah, I tried to specify that it was special, but didn't want to go on a tangent about it.  Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: I only mentioned it because a few days ago I saw someone try to use that string in a static script file to test jsonp and couldn't figure out why it wasn't working